# How to XAML converters do more?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In angular can do a number of filters on the text for example:

```
<div ng-bind="vm.value | filter1| filter2| filter3"
```

And when the sequence is maintained.
How is this done in XAML? in particular xamarin .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by using converters in Xamarin Forms:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamlSamples.SharedResourcesPage"
         Title="Shared Resources Page">
 <ContentPage.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
     <local:DoubleToIntConverter x:Key="intConverter" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
 </ContentPage.Resources>
  <StackLayout>
   <Label Text="{Binding Color.R,
          Converter={StaticResource intConverter},
          ConverterParameter=255,
          StringFormat='R={0:X2}'}" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Converter:

```
class DoubleToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double multiplier;

        if (!Double.TryParse(parameter as string, out multiplier))
            multiplier = 1;

        return (int)Math.Round(multiplier * (double)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double divider;

        if (!Double.TryParse(parameter as string, out divider))
            divider = 1;

        return ((double)(int)value) / divider;
    }
}
```

More information here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Comment: Found a nice tip from the Xamarin Sport App, which involves adding adding an instance property to all converters so that they only need to be created once during the life of the app. So you could add the following: public static DoubleToIntConverter Instance = new DoubleToIntConverter(); then in you XAML you reference it like so: <Label Text="{Binding Color.R,
          Converter={x:Static DoubleToIntConverter.Instance},
          ConverterParameter=255,
          StringFormat='R={0:X2}'}" />